# Is it not possible to get the birthday of a user with JSON WS in Liferay?

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay for user management and an external application that communicates with Liferay using JSON Web services. When I call the web service `/user/get-user-by-id`

```
{
"agreedToTermsOfUse": false,
"comments": "",
"companyId": 10153,
"contactId": 16003,
"createDate": 1390552990000,
"defaultUser": false,
"emailAddress": "basketball@liferay.com",
"emailAddressVerified": false,
"facebookId": 0,
"failedLoginAttempts": 0,
"firstName": "Basketball1",
"graceLoginCount": 0,
"greeting": "Welcome Basketball1!",
"jobTitle": "",
"languageId": "en_US",
"lastFailedLoginDate": null,
"lastLoginDate": null,
"lastLoginIP": "",
"lastName": "",
"ldapServerId": -1,
"lockout": false,
"lockoutDate": null,
"loginDate": null,
"loginIP": "",
"middleName": "",
"modifiedDate": 1390992862465,
"openId": "",
"portraitId": 18708,
"reminderQueryAnswer": "",
"reminderQueryQuestion": "",
"screenName": "basketball1",
"status": 0,
"timeZoneId": "Europe/Paris",
"userId": 16002,
"uuid": "3ce789e0-4cb5-45bf-b57e-68c44ea3ec04"
}
```

And some information as birthday is missed. I see that also I can change the birthday using the web services `/user/update-user` but I cannot retrieve the original value. How can I get the birthday information? Is there any other method to obtain the missing data?

And...  if I want to update any field of the user and in `/user/update-user` I MUST put the birthday and I cannot retrieve the old value... the birthday will be lost!

Comment: Liferay is not storing user's birthday information in user_ table rather it stores it in contact table. Unfortunately there is no webservice methods exposed for contact table, you may have to write your own web-service methods using service-builder.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have expected to find this information in the user as it is requested when creating a user. Then, the information can be obtained through `contact/get-contact` service. Is not needed to write my own web-service. Now it is working fine. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user birthday through contact service:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/contact/get-contact/contact-id/10202
```

where id is the user-id

Comment: Yes, as commented in the discussion between @Panjak and me.

Comment: Good solutions come together :)